# Generate a list of randomly distributed $1$s and $0$s with fixed proportion of $1$s

Tags: list-manipulation, random, binary

I need to simulate a random initial state of an 1D cellular automaton, but with different 'densities' of filled cells.

Let's say the size of the list is $N$, then I need to be able to fix a number $P$ such that there are exactly $P$ $1$s and $N-P$ $0$s.

`RandomInteger` gives $1$s or $0$s with probability $p=1/2$, but first, I still din't work out how to correctly modify the probability so it can change from $0$ to $1$, and second, I would prefer for the number to be exact.

In other words, I have $P$ $1$s and $N-P$ $0$s and I need to randomly and uniformly distribute them inside a singe list. I'm not sure how to do that efficiently.

I suppose I could create a list of all the possible positions and use `RandomSample[list,P]` to fill them with $1$s. But is there a better way?

---

> Important point! $N$ will be very large (up to 100 000).

Comment: You want to first create a list with the correct numbers of 1s and 0s and then create a random permutation, which you can d with `RandomSample`. Therefore try: `RandomSample[Join[ConstantArray[1, p], ConstantArray[0, n - p]]]` where `n` is the length of the list overall and `p` the number of 1s.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli, thank you, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need precisely `m` zeros and `n` ones in random order, just put them in a list and use [`RandomSample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSample.html) to shuffle it.

```
m = 10;
n = 10;

RandomSample[ConstantArray[0, m]~Join~ConstantArray[1, n]]
(* {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: Will it work efficiently with large lists (see my edit)?

Comment: @YuriyS Yes. Try it.

Comment: Szabolcs, ok, thank you. I don't have access to Mathematica right now, that's why I was asking